# Adding a title to a plot that was made in an R function

Tags: r, function, plot

I made a function that graphs the competition model between owls and hawks. I want to have different titles for each plot. Can I add a title after it has been plotted or do I need to get rid of the function and plot individually? Ideally, I would like to keep as a function. Thank you in advance!

````
```{r}
#setting x axis, days
x <- c(0:30)

#function that takes initial conditions and calculates from 1 to 30 days
comp <- function(o, h, x){
  for (j in 1:30){
    on = 0.2*o[j] - .001*h[j]*o[j] + o[j]
    hn = 0.3*h[j] - .002 *h[j]*o[j] + h[j]
    o <- append(o, on)
    h <- append(h, hn)
    }
  plot(x, o, col="blue", type="l", ylim=range(c(o,h)), xlab="X", ylab="On, Hn", pch=8)
lines(x, h, col="red", type="l", pch=10)
legend("topleft", legend=c("Owls", "Hawks"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
}


comp(151, 199, x) 
comp(149, 201, x)
comp(10, 10, x)
```
````

Comment: You can use `title()` after the function. Or you can modify your function to optionally take a title as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add arguments to your function including title. Alternatively, you could use `ggplot2`, which allows you to add or modify many components of your graphs. The following code roughly reproduce your function with `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c(0:30)
comp_2 <- function(o, h, x){
  for (j in 1:30){
    on = 0.2*o[j] - .001*h[j]*o[j] + o[j]
    hn = 0.3*h[j] - .002 *h[j]*o[j] + h[j]
    o <- append(o, on)
    h <- append(h, hn)
  }
data.frame(x = x, o = o, h = h) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = o, col="Owls")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y =h, col="Hawks")) +
  theme_bw()+
 labs(x = "X", y="On, Hn") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = c(0.1, 0.8))
}
comp_2(151, 199, x) + labs(title = "Figure 1") # add others if needed
comp_2(149, 201, x) + labs(title = "Figure 2")
comp_2(10, 10, x) + labs(title = "Figure 3")
```